# Proof of coercivity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have the intution that the functional $$A(u)=\int_\Omega |\nabla u(x)|^2\ dx\ +\ 1/2\cdot\int_\Omega (1-|u(x)|^2)^2\ dx \quad \forall u \in H^1(\Omega) $$ where $\Omega $ is a bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^N$, is coercive, that is $$  \lim_{\Vert u \Vert\rightarrow \infty}A(u)=\infty$$ where $\Vert u\Vert^2=  \int_\Omega|\nabla u|^2\ +\int_\Omega | u |^2 $. I dont know how to prove it. I am stucked. Is there any theorial result that can be helpful in order to prove it that I should know?

This is my attempt:
$$ A(u)\geq   \int_\Omega |\nabla u(x)|^2\ dx\ +1/2 \int_{|u|>2} (1-|u(x)|^2)^2\ dx \geq \int_\Omega |\nabla u(x)|^2\ dx\ +1/2 \int_{|u|>2} |u(x)|^2\ dx = \Vert u \Vert^2-    \int_{|u|<2} |u(x)|^2\ dx  =   \Vert u \Vert^2-C\rightarrow \infty$$ am I right?

Answer (score 4):

Your functional is not coercive. For example, fix $\Omega = [0,1] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and consider $u_n(x) = x^{n+1}$. Then $\nabla u(x) = (n+1)x^n$ and so 
$$\|u\|^2 = (n+1)^2 \int_0^1 x^{2n} dx + \int_0^1 x^{2(n+1)} dx = \frac{(n+1)^2}{2n} + \frac{1}{2(n+1)} \to \infty$$ as $n \to \infty$. However
$$Au_n = (n+1) \int_0^1 x^n dx + \int_0^1 (1- x^{2(n+1)})^2 dx = 2 + \frac{1}{4n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1}$$
is a bounded sequence.

---

Edit: After you've edited, your new functional is coercive by basically your attempt, except for the fact a factor of a half mysteriously goes missing at some point. This is easily dealt with however since you only want a lower bound that doesn't care about multiplicative factors.

Comment: Another question, why $1-|u|^2\in L^2(\Omega)$ if $u\in H^1(\Omega)$??

Comment: It needn't be in general (unless you assume enough to get this from a sobolev embedding). I assume the correct interpretation of your problem is that $A$ takes values in $[0,\infty]$ and if $Au = \infty$ then you have no problem with coercivity.

Comment: I see... so my functional is not well defined on $H^1(\Omega )$.

Comment: Well, it's well defined as a functional to the extended real line. Note that all the integrands are non-negative and so the integrals still all make sense.